# Clojure: Conditionally call a function and rest of the other functions by default

Tags: algorithm, clojure, logical-operators

I want to execute a function conditionally and rest of the other functions by default irrespective of the first condition being true or false.

Ex: `

```
(defn- publish
  [txn publisher domain-slug template first-published-at]
  (if (= 2 2) 
      (do (somefunc txn publisher)))
  (firstfunc txn publisher domain-slug first-published-at)
  (secondfunc txn publisher)
)
```

`

I want to execute all the three functions if true and execute the last two functions if false.

Comment: Your code already does what you describe, so what's the question?

Comment: It's not executing the rest of the statements if true.

Comment: Use `when` instead of `if`

Comment: Yes it is. If you wrote this code, then after `somefunc` returns, `firstfunc` and `secondfunc` are definitely called next. If you think that's not happening, perhaps it's because `somefunc` never returns?

Comment: Fooled by oddly formatted code...

Answer (score 4):

`when` is intended to be used used for conditional side-effects.  e.g.

```
(defn- publish
  [txn publisher domain-slug template first-published-at]
  (when (= 2 2) 
    (somefunc txn publisher))
  (firstfunc txn publisher domain-slug first-published-at)
  (secondfunc txn publisher))
```

Comment: It's true that this is better style, but it behaves exactly the same as the code in the question.

Comment: It should do exactly what OA wanted - do `firstfunc` and `secondfunc` always - but if condition fulfilled in addition before them `somefunc`.

Comment: Yes, of course. But my point is, the code in the question *also* already does exactly what the author wanted. So changing `if` to `when` isn't going to make any difference to whatever problem is actually leading to the question.

Comment: But it does what OP wanted. Plus the `when` has an implicit `do` so he saves the `do` - the `when` also makes clear that there is no alternative - only the consequent. So it improves readability.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 (cond 
   (= 2 2) (some-fn arg1 arg2)
    :else  (do
             (firstfunc txn publisher domain-slug first-published-at)
             (secondfunc txn publisher)))
```

Refer here https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/cond
for syntax